# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility - Error saving configuration OpsHub-001105

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

In the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility, we get an error when pressing "Finish" on a new migration.

The error message says:

> Configuration failed due to following reason(s):
>   com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException: Opshub-001105: Can not
>   parse date "Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00". Expected format EE MMM d yyyy
>   H:m:s

We have tried changing the Regional settings to "English (United States)" and restarting the server, didn't help.

Last entry in the OpsHub.log:

```
        06/23/2017 10:50:06,644 ERROR [http-nio-8989-exec-7] (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OpsHub-001105: Can not parse date "Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00". Expected format EEE MMM d yyyy H:m:s
    com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException: OpsHub-001105: Can not parse date "Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00". Expected format EEE MMM d yyyy H:m:s
        at com.opshub.utils.DateUtils.convertStringToCalendar(DateUtils.java:235)
        at com.opshub.utils.DateUtils.convertDateStringToTimeStamp(DateUtils.java:218)
        at com.opshub.eai.business.EaiConfigBO.insertPollingTimeKeyForAudit(EaiConfigBO.java:1072)
        at com.opshub.eai.business.EaiConfigBO.createOrUpdateEAIConnector(EaiConfigBO.java:382)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.createIntegration(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:1320)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.generateIntegrationsAndMappings(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:1049)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.generateIntegrationAndMappings(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:504)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.generateIntegration(ConfigServiceImpl.java:197)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.generateIntegrations(ConfigServiceImpl.java:159)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93f9f889.CGLIB$generateIntegrations$11(<generated>)
        at com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93f9f889$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d590bcb9.invoke(<generated>)
...
```

Comment: What is the version of OVSMU that you are using?

Comment: The version is v2.6.1.001

Comment: What's the data and time formats of you OS? What's the result if you change the region location and formats to Poland?

Comment: Changing to Poland did not help. Same error.

Comment: What's the data and time formats of you OS?

Comment: Hi, Changing the user locale to US should solve the issue. But it also means that you'll have to run the tool with that user. In the services.msc, find "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" and override it to log on as the user whose locale you had changed to 'us' based value. Let us know if it works

Comment: Thanks, setting locale to US and changing the user on the service to my user worked.

Comment: @OpsHubInc. You can post an answer for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that is being fixed in the tool. Until then the workaround for this issue would be to change the machine locale to 'US'.

Once you change the locale (by being logged in as some machine user), you'll have to configure your OS to run the tool as that user (since by default 'Local System' runs most services). So, open services.msc, find the service named 'OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility' and change it's log-on user as the one whose locale you changed.

Now, restart the utility and the workaround should help you avoid the error.